# Error code 400 returns when trying to upload file to Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am a newbie to AWS and right now I am trying to write a standalone Java application to upload a PDF to AWS S3. However, error: 400 is returned.

Can anybody give me some general directions on how to troubleshoot this error?

```
public class App {

private static String PDF_PATH = "/tmp/pdf-test.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // prepare AWS credential
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxx",
            "yyy");
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("aaa")
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).build();

    // upload a test PDF
    byte[] pdfDoc = Files.readAllBytes((new File(PDF_PATH)).toPath());
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("aaa", "bbb",
            new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(pdfDoc)));
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentType("application/pdf");
    metadata.setContentLength(pdfDoc.length);
    request.setMetadata(metadata);
    s3Client.putObject(request);
}
```

}

Comment: Code 400 means bad request. The PutObjectRequest constructor is 
PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, File file), you are providing for the last parameter a String instead of a File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on what @AlexGoja said, there are [three constructors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) for a `PutObjectRequest`.  [One of them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes three Strings.  However, the third string parameter is not a Base64 encoded file.  I'm not sure where you got that.  You want to use [the constructor that takes a File](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#PutObjectRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-) to upload the file:

```
public class App {

private static String PDF_PATH = "/tmp/pdf-test.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // prepare AWS credential
    BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxx",
            "yyy");
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion("aaa")
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).build();

    // upload a test PDF
    File pdfFile = new File(PDF_PATH);
    PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest("aaa", "bbb", pdfFile );
    ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
    metadata.setContentType("application/pdf");
    metadata.setContentLength(pdfFile.length());
    request.setMetadata(metadata);
    s3Client.putObject(request);
}

}
```